# Reverse printing of an array

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

(Java beginner)
I came up with a code that would display an int array in reverse and although I know there's probably a better way to do it, I think this logic should work:

```
for(int i = 0, j = numList.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        int temp = numList[i];
        numList[i]  = numList[j];
        numList[j] = temp;
        System.out.print("Reverse order: " + temp + " ");
    }
```

What I don't understand is that when I enter 5 numbers, the console only shows the first two numbers and it ends there:

```
1
2
3
4
5
Reverse order: 1 2
```

What's wrong here and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is just faulty. Use this instead.

```
for(int i = numList.Length - 1; i >= 0;i--)
{
    int temp = numList[i];
    System.out.print("Reverse order: " + temp + " ");
}
```

In your code, you increment i and decrement j, meaning that if you'd loop untill your condition is satisfied, you'd get about half the loop done. Try and create a table of the values of your loop step by step, you'll see what I mean :)

Comment: are you sure this runs? where is j here?

Comment: @Nazgul Good point, I didn't even look at the body :P I honestly don't know what he tried to reach with the body of his code. He just wants to display them in reverse order, or am I misreading something in his question? :P

Comment: i think he is trying to reverse an array. This new code example would just print it in reverse order. There is a far simpler way to do reverse printing than this. 

But your earlier example was correct to what he wanted....you just missed the j in loop declaration rest was good enough.

Comment: @Nazgul "I came up with a code that would display an int array in reverse" -> Display in reverse <-.

I really think he didn't want to reverse the elements, just display them reversely.

Comment: @DylanMeeus Makes sense, but then when I run it it doesn't display the first number I entered. For example, I enter 1 2 3 4 5, the console would then display 5 4 3 2 but not the 1. I think it's because of `i > 0`. This part of the code would continue running until it reaches the '0' position, but when it does, it will terminate before it displays the integer '0' is holding. How can this be fixed?

Comment: @braindead use i >= 0 instead, I'll make the edit :)

Comment: @DylanMeeus I always had this assumption you couldn't use = in termination statements lol. It works! Thanks man

Comment: @braindead You can because it's part of something. you can't use that for an equality check. (e.g: if(price = 0)) because then you are setting the price to be 0 which isn't a boolean operation. You could write: if(price==0) :) And you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

i++ and j-- along with the loop iteration condition of i < j would become false when i and j reach the middle of the array. So essentially your for loop is only working up the first half of the loop. I didnt run you code but this is the first observation i made.

Comment: I knew this was wrong for some reason, but I thought the statement         `numList[i]  = numList[j];` would somehow fix that. :/